# What does this python-config option mean? (installing python from a downloaded compressed .tgz folder)

Tags: python, linux, installation, configure, python-config

I am referencing this Medium article, https://medium.com/@lupiel/installing-python-from-a-tgz-file-a-step-by-step-guide-4cf5f4a17a86, and it recommends tagging on the following option to the ./configure script when installing python on linux.

```
LDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath=/opt/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/lib,--disable-new-dtags
```

I've looked at the man page for python-configure and it is relatively short. I didn't find anything in `python3-config --help` either. It tells me that `LDFLAGS` "print the flags that should be passed to the linker." I read that a linker is a symlink? Regardless, this is the extent of information I've been able to find. I don't understand what the rest does.

Comment: Search [`man gcc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) for `-Wl,option`. Read in [`man ld`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld) about the linker options `-rpath` and `--disable-new-dtags`.

Answer (score 1):

These configure options will build a shared library, which means that the Python interpreter will be contained mostly in an external `libpython3.so` file, and the `python` executable will just be a small shim (maybe 15 kb) that will link to the libpython shared object.

These LDFLAGS, combined with the `--enable-shared` option the article mentioned, means that the `python` executable will be configured with a [run-time search path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath) of `/opt/python/${PYTHON_ VERSION}/lib` to find this shared object, i.e. at startup time it will look for a `libpython3.so` file in there to dynamically link against.

This is not the default way to build CPython. By default the interpreter is burnt into the Python executable, i.e. the `python` exe will be much bigger (megabytes) and an external `libpython3.so` file will not be generated at all. Doing it this way, without `--enable-shared`, will result in a slightly faster and more memory-efficient build of CPython.

I do not recommend using `--enable-shared`, unless you specifically need it (for e.g. embedding). If you don't know what it's for, you don't need it.